# Tapping on a button in UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar

I have a custom UIToolBar with an button(image) on left and a text on right. When I tap on the button, only the image which I used for the button is tappable and not the entire left section of the toolbar. Do I need to have a image which covers the entire section to make the entire section tappale? Or is there any way which UIToolBar provides to make the entire item tappable?

Below is the code to add these items in my custom class subclassing UIToolBar:

```
[self setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:AddBarButton, FlexibleSpaceBarButton, TextBarItem, nil]];
```

[image]

Comment: How are you creating the button? Most likely, you will have to create an image which covers the entire section.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a button ... only the button is tap-able. To do what you want, you could add a gesture recognizer to the view and respond to taps that way:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gr;
    gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
             initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
    [yourView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
    [gr release];
```

Of course, this will only work if you have a "subview" that is containing your button.

Comment: Would that possibly interfere with the operation of the button? Seems unnecessary to mimic the effects of UIButton instead of just making a larger image for the button. Unless a larger image distorts the view.

Comment: I would add the gesture recognizer instead of the button. Just add a subview UIImageView to show the image of the button. The only real downside I can think of is that when you click and hold the button, you won't see the button change state.